# Is SoapType.Decimal a valid value?

Tags: apex, data-types, decimal, enum

[Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_enum_Schema_SOAPType.htm) for SoapType enum does not list Decimal as a member. But it's possible to compile a class which uses SoapType.Decimal.

Could this be a problem if we use such code in a managed package?

Comment: It's not going anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is a valid value. Any `Number` field has this soap type tied to its describe. It's very firmly rooted within the platform.

I have built several tools which depend on this enum. Even though none of them were managed, I am certain I'm far from alone.

If Salesforce removes this value, they will break a massive amount of code. It would not happen without significant lead time.

Comment: Then what's the difference with INTEGER? Could you please give an example SObject and field? `field.getDescribe().getSoapType()` to return  Schema.SoapType.Decimal